# 'Sort by' options hidden by header on mobile web

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, mobile-chrome

I've just come across this curio on the Full Site on Mobile. When I tap the 'more' button for ordering posts, I can't see the top. I assume it's stuck behind the header which must have a higher `z-index`.

Could the developers make the top bounding box include the header height?

[image: screenshot showing how the sort options box gets stuck]

I'm using Chrome on Android.

Comment: I reproduced this on iOS Safari. However, the only thing you’re missing in that menu is the bountied option, which you can replicate with just a custom filter.

Comment: @Laurel yeah, I'm not worried about missing stuff - I rarely use it (which is why I've only just noticed). I'm only posting this because it's broken and probably should be fixed :)

Comment: (*["curio"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curio#Noun)* - *"A strange and interesting object; something that evokes curiosity."*)

Comment: @Peter exactly.